# How to run a JS script by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement on my site a demonstration of code examples.
https://yuricoder.dev/docs/nunjucks/templates/code-example/code-example-test.html

I want to make the code from the example run when you click on the button.

The most obvious way is to put an example in a function and call with 'onclick', but it is not suitable because the code examples themselves may contain functions.

In the code below, I get a function inside another function, so the script does not run.

```html
<button title="Run" onclick="example1()"></button>

<script>

function example1() { 

  // javascript (example-1)
  function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a < b) return -1;
  }

  let arr = [ 1, 2, 15 ];
  arr.sort(compareNumeric);
  alert(arr);  // 1, 2, 15

}

</script>
```

I would like to do as implemented on this site https://javascript.info/bind
It uses the attribute data-action="run". But I can't figure out how to link it to my example.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is.  This code looks fine to me.

Comment: This code demonstrably works.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Strange, but true-the code works. Previously, the script for some reason did not run...

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
<button id="fooBtn">X</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function applyBindings() {
    document.getElementById("fooBtn").addEventListener("click", compareNumeric);
}

applyBindings();


function compareNumeric(a, b) {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a < b) return -1;
}

let arr = [ 1, 2, 15 ];
arr.sort(compareNumeric);
alert(arr);  // 1, 2, 15
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your function like you are doing and inside add another function which executes right away:

```html
<button title="Run" onclick="example1()"></button>
```

```js
function example1() {

  (function() {
    alert('I run when example1 runs!')
  })();

}
```

Comment: The OP wants to trigger the function using a button.

Comment: Then show him *how*.  "I want to make the code from the example run when you click on the button."  Your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: I am trying to help you by letting you know you did not answer the question.  Answer it and I will remove the downvote.  This is called "feedback".